# How to make a kiosk app iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

How can i create a kiosk app for the iPhone?

What is the best way to upload content in sections html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML or PDF would work fine. You can use a UIWebView to display both formats. Or if there is a standard way of laying everything out that will not change, you can use XML (or RSS).

Comment: Yes but how can i make the app. Its a simple app and upload like magazine?

Comment: What do you mean? Choose one of the formats I gave you then create a UIWebView (or whatever you are going to use in your app). Download the content and display it to the user.

Comment: Yes I understand that part :P. What I don't get it its. I will upload the app to kiosk like normal app? And the icon will be the magazine or how do i make that? So the people could but it in the kiosk store. @Jack Humphries

Comment: @Ernesto You can either put the app on the App Store and get the app to the kiosk that way or sign the app with your development certificate and put it on the kiosk (limited to 100 devices and only lasts a year). If you want to pay $299 (instead of $99 for previous) you can sign up for the "Enterprise Program" and put the app on as many devices as you want with no limit. You can only put it on devices that belong to your company (not sure who owns the kiosk). If you want to change the icon, then you should look into Newsstand apps. They're really easy to set up.

Comment: Hi @Jack Humphries sorry what I mean its the Newsstand apps. In my country it call (traduced) Kiosk. Sorry about that. And to the newsstand how could i upload it? Like a normal app?

Comment: @Ernesto Yes, you can upload it like a normal app. Sorry for misunderstanding you! Just a note, you'll need to insert an auto-renewing subscription in order to submit your app to the store. But the rest is the same. You don't even need to have a push notification system up and running for it to be accepted.

Comment: Here's a tutorial I looked at when I was thinking about making a Newsstand app. It includes sample code. http://www.viggiosoft.com/blog/blog/2011/10/17/ios-newsstand-tutorial/